# exiting a for loop in python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

```
 owner_details = open ("owner_details","r")
        for line in owner_details.readlines():
            if RegistrationNumber  in line:
              vehicles_speeding  = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
              vehicles_speeding.write(line)
              vehicles_speeding.close()
              print ("Details for registration",[RegistrationNumber],"have been added to the 'vehicles_speeding' file")
              time.sleep(2)
              view = input("Match found for registration number in 'owner_details' file. Do you wish to view details \n:")
              view = view.upper()
              if view == "YES":
                  print (line)
            else:
                continue 


        owner_details = open ("owner_details","r")         
        for line in owner_details.readlines():
            if RegistrationNumber not in line:
                add= input("No match found for registration number do you want to add details for registration number ? \n:")
                add = add.upper()
            if add == "YES":
                name = input("enter vehicle owners full name \n:")
                adress = input ("Enter vehicle owners adress \n:")
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write("\n"+"NAME: ")
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write(name)
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write("ADDRESS: ")
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write(' '+adress)
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write("REGISTRATION NUMBER: ")
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write( ' '+RegistrationNumber+' ')
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write("SPEED: ")
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write("%2.f"%(Speed))
                vehicles_speeding = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
                vehicles_speeding.write(' '+"m/s")
                vehicles_speeding.close()
                print ("Details have been added to file")
```

How can I stop the code from executing the second for loop if the registration number is found in the first for loop.

Comment: why are you opening the same file several times? what are you trying to do here?

Comment: [`break` or `continue`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops): `break` if you want to end the loop, `continue` if you want to move to the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Give more details when you ask questions. If I understand you, then what you want to do is search through a file for a particular number; if the number is found, open another file and make a note, else if the number isn't found, give the user the option of adding that number to the first file. Your code is horribly inefficient: you open the same file every time you call `write()` and you are using 2 loops when one would do. Try this instead:

```
owner_details = open("owner_details","r")
vehicles_speeding  = open ("vehicles_speeding","a")
for line in owner_details:
     if RegistrationNumber in line:
         vehicles_speeding.write(line)
         print ("Details for registration",RegistrationNumber,"have been added to the 'vehicles_speeding' file")
         view = input("Match found for registration number in 'owner_details' file.\nDo you wish to view details:").upper()
         if view.startswith("Y"):
            print(line)
         break 
else:      # this branch is run, if the FOR loop completed without breaking
    add = input("No match found for registration number.\nDo you want to add details for registration number?:").upper()
    if add.startswith("Y"):
        details = []
        name = input("enter vehicle owners full name: ")
        adress = input ("Enter vehicle owners address: ")
        details.append("\nNAME: ")   # Too many concatenations
        details.append(name)
        details.append("ADDRESS: ")   # append is cheaper 
        details.append(adress)       # than writing to the file every time
        details.append("REGISTRATION NUMBER: ")
        details.append(RegistrationNumber)
        details.append("SPEED: ")
        details.append("%2.f" %(Speed))  #not really sure what format u want
        details.append(" m/s")
        vehicles_speeding.write("".join(details))   # write everything at once
        print("Details have been added to file")

vehicles_speeding.close()   # now you can close them
owner_details.close()
```

To make it even more efficient, you could allocate a fixed amount of space to `details` to prevent its growth (something like `details = [""]*9`), and then fill in the spaces.